# How to display information when a certain dataset is loaded into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I need to show the quality information of a dataset that was manually created by me, that is saved as a text file. The text file will "pop up" when the dataset is added into QGIS. I have no experience in creating plugins in QGIS. Can you help me with the approach to create a plugin for the above mentioned purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a plugin for that.
Just create a new action that opens your txt file on click.
You can find help how to create actions here:
http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/create_vector_data/actions.html

After you have configured an action (to open your txt file), just use the actions box in the menu.

Comment: Also , i am planning to create a plug in to create quality information. The plug in should do following actions: 
1) To add Dataset for which the quality information is to be added.
2)  View the quality info if available.
3) Create a new one or edit existing.
4) Save it to the Database along with the dataset.
I need to know whether all the tasks mentioned above is possible to create or not. If possible send me the links where I can get ideas.

Comment: @user32462 Please open a new thread if you have more questions and accept this answer if it solves the problem described in the question on the top.